# jQuery function run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html file with this code inside it:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#RadniNalog").click(function () {

            $("#AdminContent").html();
            $("#AdminContent").append("<button class='btn1'>Novi nalog</button><br><br>");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/RadniNalog/Lista",
                contentType: "application.json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var htmlToAppend;
                    $("#RadniNalog").addClass("activated");
                    htmlToAppend += "<table>";
                    htmlToAppend += "<tr><th>Broj naloga</th></tr>";
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        htmlToAppend += "<tr><td>" + data[index].brDok + "</td></tr>";
                    });

                    htmlToAppend += "</table>";
                    $("#AdminContent").append(htmlToAppend);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Other thing i have in that file is only div`#AdminContent` and button `#RadniNalog`.

I get data from my API and i build string which is needed to append on page. Problem is that my page appear

```
undefined
<table>
//everything else it needs to
```

So as you can see problem is `undefined` part. I tried tracking when does it happend and it does happen when i `append` to my div. Later i suspected on `each` loop so i removed it and again it displays `undefined` and after it empty table.

So why does it append `undefined`? It looks like for some reason it run this function twice.

EDIT: I have declared `var htmlToAppend = "Something"` and instead of `undefined` it displays `Something` but still why?

Comment: Why are you setting it to `undefined` or `Something` if you want it to be equal to an empty string?

Comment: I am not setting it to `undefined`, and i set it to `something` for testing purpose to see if it is appending that var two times or something else

Comment: By doing `var htmlToAppend;`, you are in fact setting it to undefined. `undefined + "foo"` = `undefinedfoo`

Comment: Oh. Yea i am setting it to `undefined`. Still why does it referee to this problem?

Comment: because... that's what it do? when you try to use string concatenation with something that isn't a string, it will attempt to convert the something to a string, or the string to the something, depending on what the something is.

Comment: Ohhhh now i get it. So if i i doesn't set anything to `var` and later i do `+=` it is not adding string to empty one but it thinks it has value of `undefined`

Comment: have you console logged to see whether ajax is retrieving it properly

Comment: @KevinB Yeap, it did solve my problem. So simple but comming from different language. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
var htmlToAppend;
```

to this:

```
var htmlToAppend = "";
```

This why after the first append it will contain the initial value which is an empty String. (Not undefined or "Something" as in your example)

Answer (score -1):

var htmlToAppend = "";

You need assign empty string when create var. Later you use operator "+=". It adds text to already existed content of var htmlToAppend.